# How many different http client library I can use in a same project?

Tags: android

I have requirement to update my application with another project module. I used default http client in my application. retorfit2 library used in newly adding module. Does it make any problem to my existing process. I do the same for another module with same library, but I leads to many crashes and unknown exceptions.

Help me to clarify? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem using several libs for that.